# Jquery Token Input - Multiple PropertyToSearch

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, jquery-tokeninput

I am using Jquery Token input in my MVC project for searching and selecting Users List.

I want to compare the 3 fields during the search

```
UserName, FullName, and Email Id
```

and Should highlight the type word in all these fields.

How can i do that.?

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: if i type 'xy', then it should list users with userName containing 'xy', Fullname contining 'xy' and email id containing 'xy'

Comment: you are providing some local date instead of 3rd party search call, in which you want want to search according to these fields?

Comment: i am not using Local data. In the controller i have the logic to search in all the fields.  but it is hitting the controller action  for the first time and data is loaded in cache. So second time,search will be happening on this cached data. hence it is not comparing all the fields . it will hit the controller action only if none of the cached data matches the typed letters.